# Python: creating customer sort method & loop stops before list sorted

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to create a custom sort method in which I take a list that is not in numerical order and puts the list into order from lowest to highest.

***The program should take the following list...***

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4]
```

***and *print* it as follows...***

```
arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

***As it stands, my code reads...***

```
def sort(list):
for i in range(1, len(list)):
    if list[i] < list[i - 1]:
        temp = list[i - 1]
        list[i - 1] = list[i]
        list[i] = temp
        print arr       
sort(arr)
```

***And my output is this...***

```
[1, 2, 1, 3, 4]
```

It seems as though the function runs through the list once, reorders the numbers once and stops before they are all in numerical order. How do I make it run through the list as many times as it takes to put all of the numbers where they should be?

Comment: Why not just use the existing list.sort() method? Might this be homework?

Comment: 1. Don't shadow `list`. 2. Just use `sorted`. 3. *"How do I make it run through the list as many times as it takes to put all of the numbers where they should be?"* - `while`, perhaps?

Comment: @BasJansen I am working on my algorithms for job interviews. ;)

Comment: Might I ask why someone down voted this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why won't you just:

```
def sort_list(my_list):
    print sorted(my_list)


def main():
    arr = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4]
    sort_list(arr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This will have the following output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you don't want to use a built-in function just do this:

```
def sort_list(new_list):
    data_list = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4]

    while data_list:
        minimum = data_list[0]  # arbitrary number in list
        for x in data_list:
            if x < minimum:
                minimum = x
        new_list.append(minimum)
        data_list.remove(minimum)

    print new_list


def main():
    new_list = []
    sort_list(new_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This will have the same output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```